# OnPaint not triggered?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint

I have a WinForm where I override the `OnPaint`, this form is a *MDI parent*. The `OnPaint` is however not triggered even when the `WinForm` is shown with a child? I have tried to use `Invalidate` and the `Update` but does not trigger the `OnPaint` eather?

I have tried the Paint event but its the same here?

Any idea?

Comment: it's practically impossible, that OnPaint is not triggered, you would be even able to see the form so... There is something else is wrong. Can provide some code ?

Comment: You have not determined the incorrect behavior because I can GUARANTEE you that the OnPaint event is  being triggered if you can see the control on the form while the application is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `Form.IsMdiContainer`, it actually just adds a `MdiClient` control to the form. Your child forms are actually displayed within the MdiClient control and not the form itself. Your form's Paint event is being raised, but the MdiClient is docked in the form so you don't see it. You need to access the MdiClient's paint event instead.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        mdiClient = Controls[0] as MdiClient;

        if (mdiClient != null) {
            mdiClient.Paint += OnMdiClientPaint;
        }
    }

    private MdiClient mdiClient;

    private void OnMdiClientPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, mdiClient.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, how can I disable the base.OnPaint(...) ?
`//base.OnPaint (e);`